.Net Maui CarouselView with image source binding on iOS works on simulator but not on iPhone
Using .net MAUI 8
I am breaking my head over this... I have a carouselview which appears to be working well in iOS simulator but once deployed to a physical device, does not behave as anticipated.
I am binding the Image "Source" property in a CarouselView's Datatemplate to a collection of strings that contain the file names of MauiImage resources from my project. See below:
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"  IndicatorView="indicatorView"> 
   <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
          <Image Source="{Binding .}"/>
     </DataTemplate>
   </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>

As mentioned, the "Images" is a collection of strings that match the names of the MauiImages in my resources/images folder.
All the images in the project are defined in the .csproj file as <MauiImage>
I know the correct case sensitive file names are being loaded into the binding, because if I replace the Image with a Label - the correct name appears.
I tried the whole thing with an EmbeddedResource instead of a MauiImage (and used it as is or with the community toolkit ImageResourceConverter) with no luck
Can anyone help me understand where I went wrong?
Thanks!

add x:DataType="ImageSource" for the data template

Would one be a Release build and the other a Debug build? Checkout Compiled bindings.

@BhavaneshN no fix doing that...

@StephenQuan I would believe so...but if I change the image to a label and set the text to the bound item ({Binding .}) within the carouselview, I get the correct filename, even on a physical device

I actually solved the problem by adding  x:DataType="x:String" in the<DataTemplate> tag instead of what @BhavaneshN suggested and it works now!

I actually solved the problem by adding x:DataType="x:String" in the <DataTemplate> tag instead of what @BhavaneshN suggested and it works now!
